# Cordova geolocation plugin doesn't work on android

Tags: javascript, cordova, geolocation

I'm using cordova ,geolocation plugin for showing  latitude and longitude on android. There are plenty of question same as this so I read and tried their solution but couldn't fix the problem. The code below works perfectly on browser.

I tried 3 method, first: "navigator.geolocation.watchPosition" which returns wrong result(37.42,-122.08) in emulator(Android Studio) and doesn't return anything in device.

I also tried "navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition" with both "enableHighAccuracy" set 'true' and 'false' and I  get  timeOut error alerted.

When I delete deviceready, I don't get the timeOut, just wrong result from all three methods.

```js
(function (window) {
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
  function onDeviceReady() {
      
    var minAccuracyInMetres = 50;
    var positionWatcher;

    positionWatcher = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
      geolocationSuccess2,
      geolocationError2,
      { maximumAge: 0, timeout: 100000, enableHighAccuracy: true });

    function geolocationSuccess2(position) {
        // Reject if accuracy is not sufficient
        if (position.coords.accuracy > minAccuracyInMetres) {
            return;
        }

        // Only single position required so clear watcher
        navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(positionWatcher);

        alert('Latitude: ' + position.coords.latitude + '\n' +
                'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude + '\n' +
                'Altitude: ' + position.coords.altitude + '\n' +
                'Accuracy: ' + position.coords.accuracy + '\n' +
                'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy + '\n' +
                'Heading: ' + position.coords.heading + '\n' +
                'Speed: ' + position.coords.speed + '\n' +
                'Timestamp: ' + position.timestamp + '\n');
    };

    function geolocationError2(error) {
        console.warn("Error while retrieving current position. " +
          "Error code: " + error.code + ",Message: " + error.message);
    }

    //2

    var onSuccess1 = function (position) {
        alert('Latitude: ' + position.coords.latitude + '\n' +
              'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude + '\n' +
              'Altitude: ' + position.coords.altitude + '\n' +
              'Accuracy: ' + position.coords.accuracy + '\n' +
              'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy + '\n' +
              'Heading: ' + position.coords.heading + '\n' +
              'Speed: ' + position.coords.speed + '\n' +
              'Timestamp: ' + position.timestamp + '\n');
    };

    function onError1(error) {
        alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n' + 'highaccuracy: true');
    }
    var options1 = { maximumAge: 0, timeout: 300000, enableHighAccuracy: true };
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess1, onError1, options1);
    //3
    var onSuccess = function (position) {
        alert('Latitude: ' + position.coords.latitude + '\n' +
              'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude + '\n')
    };

    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n' + ' high accuracy:false');
    }

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, { enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 300 * 1000, maximumAge: 0 });
 }
})(window);
```

I get the watchPosition part from another question in stackoverflow.
I use cordova version: 6.4.0.
I deleted the plugin and tried again but it didn't work.
the device I'm testing with is a lenovo tablet.
Thanks a lot.

UPDATE: my Geolocation version is: 2.4.0    Is it important???

Comment: hope you have enabled GPS

Comment: yes, GPS and wifi are enabled.

Comment: on which phone you are trying to run app?

Comment: It's Lenovo tablet Model: TAB 2 A8-50LC.  Android version: 5.0.2

Comment: can you remove cordova-geo-location plugin. Use the same code to run in mobile app, without plugin. This way it will fallback to browser based geo-location. I think it may work.

Comment: didn't help! timeOut again. Actually google maps took so long to find the location, about 2-3 minutes. I don't know what to do

Comment: so you are saying after 2-3 minutes you were able to get result?
try it in some other mobiles too

Comment: no, I meant google maps took 3 minutes to find location, but my app couldn't! sorry if my English in not well.

Comment: no worries, try on some other mobile. if possible with different os version

Comment: @NitishkumarSingh Thanks for your help, I found the solution :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After two days of struggling I turned on "High accuracy" in location settings. The app Works now!!!

Comment: bro i have tried but not worked for me and why we need to High accuracy" in location settings.at my side i have already checked GPS and after GPS is check by-default " "High accuracy" mode is selected.